# How do I send an email to an address that is chosen from a dropdown menu in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to send an email to an address that is chosen from a dropdown menu in google sheets. When I do sh.getRange("C15").getValue(); it just doesn't send an email to it. It works with any other cell but this one with a dropdown menu.

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Porudžbenica')
  var imeKupca = sh.getRange('C5');
  var kupac = imeKupca.getValue();
  var mailRange = sh.getRange('C14');
  var mail = mailRange.getValue();
  var cc1 = sh.getRange("C15").getValue();
  var cc2 = sh.getRange("C16").getValue();
  //var location1 = sh.getRange('J37');
  //var location2 = sh.getRange('J38');
  //location1.setValue(cc1);
  //location2.setValue(cc2);
  var ccA = [cc1];
  var ccB = [cc2];
  MailApp.sendEmail({to:'example@email.com', cc:mail, ccA, ccB,
  subject: 'Porudžbina ' + kupac, 
  htmlBody: testTableHTML()})
};
```

Comment: Possibly you are using onEdit() simple trigger which cannot perform operations that require permission like sending emails

Comment: @Cooper which trigger should I use then?

Comment: Use an installable trigger

Comment: @Cooper I tried it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I can't work on code that I can't see and I won't follow links to your spreadsheet.  Please provide [mcve]   Please note it says minimal and reproducible

Comment: @Cooper here you go. It's missing the html part but that's not important. Also you can see my desperate attempts to get this thing to work. Cc1 and cc2 are the fields that the email should be sent to

Comment: ccA and ccB are not strings and `testTableHTML()` is undefined

Comment: Try running sendEmail in the debugger and look at executions for potential errors.

Comment: try `MailApp.sendEmail({to:"example@email.com", cc:"mail, cc1, cc2",subject: "Porudžbina " + kupac,  htmlBody: testTableHTML()})`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone god forbid encounters this, putting one email in bcc should do the trick

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('YourSheet');
  var imeKupca = sh.getRange('C5');
  var kupac = imeKupca.getValue();
  var mailRange = sh.getRange('C14');
  var mail = mailRange.getValue();
  var cc1 = sh.getRange("C15").getValue();
  var cc2 = sh.getRange("C16").getValue();
  MailApp.sendEmail({to:'example@email.com', cc:cc1, mail, bcc: cc2, //putting cc2 
    //as bcc somehow does the trick, it's probably bugged and will get fixed tho.
  subject: 'Porudžbina ' + kupac, 
  htmlBody: testTableHTML()})
};
```